# Mathjax Latex symbol square and triangle size

Tags: latex, mathjax

I have an application that uses MathJax to display some latex.
It displays most things just fine, however when I want to display a square with the command `\square`.

I'm trying this latex code as a test: `\triangle \Box \square \bigtriangleup \blacksquare`

It generates this: 
[image: Mathjax squares and triangles]

But when I generate the same commands on the mathjax site I get this:
[image: MathJax symbols as it should be]

I have included the AMSsymbols library like this:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {
        extensions: ['AMSsymbols.js']
    },
    'HTML-CSS': {
        styles: {
            '.MathJax_Display': {
                margin: '3px 0px'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using any other packages that might redefine these? If I load just `amssymb`, then the rendering in LaTeX is identical to MathJax's output.

Comment: I don't think so.

I'm loading mathjax with `https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js`

Comment: I was referring to the LaTeX side of things, i.e., `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amssymb} \begin{document} $...$ \end{document}` renders identically to MathJax.

Comment: I'm using this: `$$ ... $$` and in some cases just the singles `$ ... $`

Comment: Your output looks like the result of the Preview HTML renderer, not the HTML-CSS output.  What output renderer do you have selected (look in the MathJax contextual menu in the `Math Settings->Math Renderer` menu).

Comment: Ah, good point, so I just noticed that the output was indeed set to HTML-CSS. The mathjax live demo however uses "Common HTML".
So my guess is that's the cause of the problem. I wonder what the reason for this decision was though. What are the concequences of changing the renderer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Davide Cervone I found how to fix this.
I forced my application to use the CommonHTML output renderer by adding to my config.

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/CommonHTML", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    ...
});
```