# Unexpected italics in Mathjax symbol in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter, mathjax

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846804/mathjax-latex-symbol-square-and-triangle-size), but I don't know how to apply the solution to a Jupyter Notebook. When I use the `\square` or `\Box` symbol in a Markdown cell, it comes out in italics:

[image: rendered \Box symbol]

How can I correct this in a consistent manner? It would be great if I could do it in a global manner rather than opting for a per-notebook fix.

Comment: Not super clear which is best, but there are some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909747/how-do-i-configure-mathjax-for-ipython-notebooks).

Comment: @JoshFriedlander all of these seem like hacky workarounds... but I'll try them out!